# Multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression, user-defined-functions

I know that there are several questions around this exception on SO, but nothing seen that helps me.

I have following query giving me a `"Multi-part identifier 'claim.fiData' could not be bound"`-Exception:

```
SELECT  claim.idData FROM tabData as claim 
 INNER JOIN dbo._previousClaimsByFiData(claim.fiData) AS prevClaim 
 ON prevClaim.idData=claim.fiData 
GROUP BY claim.idData
HAVING(prevClaim.fiMaxActionCode IN (8, 23, 24) and 
prevClaim.Repair_Completion_Date >= DATEADD(day,-90,prevClaim.Repair_Completion_Date))
ORDER BY claim.idData
```

`previousClaimsByFiData` is a Table-Valued-Function that returns all previous records. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935529/wrong-order-in-table-valued-functionkeep-order-of-a-recursive-cte) if you're interested. 
Now i want to find all claims that have previous claims in the last 90 days with a maxActionCode IN(8, 23, 24).

What i've also tried was following:

```
SELECT  count(*) FROM tabData as claim 
where exists(
 select 1 from dbo._previousClaimsByFiData(claim.fiData)as prevClaim where 
  prevClaim.fiMaxActionCode IN(8, 23, 24)and 
  prevClaim.Repair_Completion_Date >= DATEADD(day,-90,claim.Repair_Completion_Date)
)
```

But that gives me a `"The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion"`-Exception.

Why do i get those exceptions and how to avoid them?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986935/call-tve-on-every-record-of-a-table-and-concat-results) which is reduced on the main problem. I can delete this when i get an answer there.

**UPDATE:**
Marc answered a simplified question according to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986935/call-tvf-on-every-record-of-a-table-and-concat-results).
So the way to go is [Cross Apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). 
But now i have the next problem what i've already mentioned above. I get a "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" Error after a few seconds.
I dont know where to add the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) because i get a "Incorrect Syntax" if i try to add it in the Inline-TVF.

My current query is:

```
SELECT  claim.idData FROM tabData  claim 
    CROSS APPLY dbo._previousClaimsByFiData(claim.fiData)AS tvfData 
GROUP BY claim.idData,claim.Repair_Completion_Date,tvfData.Repair_Completion_Date,tvfData.fiMaxActionCode
HAVING(tvfData.fiMaxActionCode IN (8, 23, 24) and 
tvfData.Repair_Completion_Date >= DATEADD(day,-90,claim.Repair_Completion_Date))
ORDER BY claim.idData
```

---

**UPDATE: the solution was to add the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) to the end of the SELECT Statement.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) to the end of the SELECT Statement.
The working query is now:

```
SELECT claim.idData,claim.Repair_Completion_Date,prevClaim.Repair_Completion_Date,prevClaim.fiMaxActionCode FROM tabData  claim 
    CROSS APPLY dbo._previousClaimsByFiData(claim.fiData)AS prevClaim 
GROUP BY claim.idData,claim.Repair_Completion_Date,prevClaim.Repair_Completion_Date,prevClaim.fiMaxActionCode
HAVING(prevClaim.fiMaxActionCode IN (8, 23, 24) and 
prevClaim.Repair_Completion_Date >= DATEADD(day,-90,claim.Repair_Completion_Date))
ORDER BY claim.idData
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

It's not the fastest query(takes more than a minute to get 23000 records in a >11Mio rec table) but it works.

UPDATE: The following query is much faster(<4 seconds) and uses `EXISTS` without `CROSS APPLY`:

```
  SELECT     idData
    FROM     tabData AS claim
    WHERE    fiProductType=1 and fiClaimStatus IN(1,5,7,8,9) AND EXISTS
         (SELECT idData
          FROM   dbo._previousClaimsByFiData(claim.fiData) AS prevClaim
          WHERE  (fiProductType = 1) AND (fimaxActionCode IN (8, 23, 24)) 
          AND (Repair_Completion_Date >= DATEADD(dd, - 90, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0, claim.Repair_Completion_Date), 0))) 
          AND (Repair_Completion_Date <= claim.Repair_Completion_Date)) 
  order by claim.idData
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```