# Call TVF on every record of a table and concat results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I thought that must be obvious but I can't figure it out.

Say there is a table `tblData` with a column `ID` and a table-valued-function (`_tvf`) that takes an `ID` as parameter. I need the results for all ID's in `tblData`.

But:

```
SELECT * FROM tblData data 
INNER JOIN dbo._tvf(data.ID) AS tvfData
   ON data.ID = tvfData.ID
```

gives me an error: `The multi-part identifier "data.ID" could not be bound`

What is the correct way to pass all ID's to this TVF and concat the results?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might need to use CROSS APPLY instead of an inner join here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tblData data 
CROSS APPLY dbo._tvf(data.ID) AS tvfData
```

This will call the TVF function for each `data.ID` of the base table and join the results to the base table's columns.

See ressources here:

- [Using CROSS APPLY in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-cross-apply-in-sql-server-2005)
- [Understanding APPLY clause in SQL Server](http://aspalliance.com/1065_Understanding_APPLY_Clause_in_SQL_Server_2005.all)
- [Using T-SQL CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c15845)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm getting a "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" Error. because this is another question, maybe you could help me there too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986240/multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound

Comment: I had to apply an OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) to the end of the Selct-Statement that calls the ITVF. Now it works, thanks again.